# Can I filter users to require a matching entry on every date in a given range?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to filter a queryset in such a way that I only retrieve users who don't have a matching object for **every date** in a range?

For example, I have a `Shift` model that includes a `ForeignKey` field pointing to an `Employee` object and a `date_requested` `DateField` indicating the date of the shift. I've also created the following query for grabbing any user that doesn't have a shift between, say, `2015-07-19` and `2015-07-25`:

```
Employee.objects.all().exclude(
    shift__date_requested__gte=datetime.date(2015, 7, 19),
    shift__date_requested__lte=datetime.date(2015, 7, 25))
```

Unfortunately this queryset doesn't catch a user that has specified shifts from 07/19 through to 07/24, but not one for 07/25. Is it possible to further refine this query to say, "the number of shifts associated with this user between `2015-07-19` and `2015-07-25` (inclusive) must be equal to the number of days within this time frame?

**Edit: Here's some code I ran according to one of the answers below:**

First, the dataset showing that Employee #10 has a `Shift` on every day between 7/19 to 7/25. This should lead to them being filtered out:

[image: Dataset]

And my filtering code

```
e = Employee.objects.all()
print('all employees:\n{0}'.format(e))
for day in range(19, 26):
    print('filtering day {0}'.format(day))
    e.filter(shift__date_requested=datetime.date(2015, 7, day))

print('filtered employees:\n{0}'.format(e))
```

And the resulting output:

```
all employees:
[<Employee: 12: ereiner@test.com ()>, <Employee: 10: alufson@test.com ()>, <Employee: 11: tjones@test.com ()>,
<Employee: 14: wmcgee@test.com ()>, <Employee: 13: wcarver@test.com ()>]
filtering day 19
filtering day 20
filtering day 21
filtering day 22
filtering day 23
filtering day 24
filtering day 25
filtered employees:
[<Employee: 12: ereiner@test.com ()>, <Employee: 10: alufson@test.com ()>, <Employee: 11: tjones@test.com ()>,
<Employee: 14: wmcgee@test.com ()>, <Employee: 13: wcarver@test.com ()>]
```

As you can see, Employee 10 isn't being filtered out. I also tried swapping out `filter()` with `exclude()` but I saw the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to get a queryset of employees who do NOT have a shift for each and every one of the given dates:

```
employees = Employee.objects.all()
for day in range(19, 26):
    employees = employees.filter(shift__date_requested=datetime.date(2015, 7, day))
```

Note that chaining filters like this [does not hit the database multiple times](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

Comment: I tried both of those and neither of them produced the desired effect. See my edit for the results of my testing

Comment: Wait, I forgot to assign the result of the filter to my `e` variable

Comment: Your second query (the one that `filter`s instead of `exclude`s) produces the desired result but when the `for` loop is finished you're left with a list of users that DO have a shift for each and every day.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer BUT it needs to be said that there's a step missing from it: you need to take this filtered list of employees and use it to exclude users in another query: `filtered_employees = Employee.objects.exclude(pk__in=employees)`. `filtered_employees` will then contain a list of users who are missing at least one shift within the date range.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right.

```
def get_num_days(d1, d2):
    return abs((d1 - d2).days)

d1 = datetime.date(2015, 7, 19)
d2 = datetime.date(2015, 7, 25)
num_days = get_num_days(d1, d2)

employees = Employee.objects \
            .annotate(num_shifts=Count('shift__date_requested', distinct=True)) \
            .exclude(num_shifts=num_days, shift__date_requested__range=(d1, d2))
```

If number of distinct shifts' `date_requested` of employee is equal to number of days between two dates, then these shifts fill every date in the range between two dates. I used `distinct` because it was not clear for me if employee's shifts could have same `date_requested`.